# Can't connect my Angular2 frontend with my Springboot JAX-RS Backend

Tags: angular, jax-rs

I have problems to connect my Angular 2 Frontend with my Backend using Springboot and CRUD operations with JAX-RS. I added an JerseyConfig and an CORS Filter but it still doesn't work.

My Backend Controller looks:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "users")
@Path("/api")
public class NoteController {


private static Map<Integer, Note> DB = new HashMap<>();     

@GET
@Path("/users")
@Produces("application/json")
public Users getUsers() {
    Users users = new Users();
    users.setUsers(new ArrayList<>(DB.values()));
    return users;
}

@GET
@Path("/user/{id}")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getUser(@PathParam("id") int id) throws 
URISyntaxException 
{
    Note user = DB.get(id);
    if(user == null) {
        return Response.status(404).build();
    }
    return Response
            .status(200)
            .entity(user)
            .contentLocation(new URI("/user-management/"+id)).build();
}

@DELETE
@Path("/user/{id}")
public Response deleteUser(@PathParam("id") int id) throws 
URISyntaxException {
    Note user = DB.get(id);
    if(user != null) {
        DB.remove(user.getId());
        return Response.status(200).build();
    }
    return Response.status(404).build();
}

@PUT
@Path("/user")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response updateUser(@PathParam("id") int id, Note user) throws 
URISyntaxException 
{
    Note temp = DB.get(id);
    if(user == null) {
        return Response.status(404).build();
    }
    temp.setFname(user.getFname());
    temp.setLname(user.getLname());
    DB.put(temp.getId(), temp);
    return Response.status(200).entity(temp).build();
}

@POST
@Path("/user")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response createUser(Note user) throws URISyntaxException 
{
    if(user.getFname() == null || user.getLname() == null) {
        return Response.status(400).entity("Please provide all mandatory 
     inputs").build();
    }
    user.setId(DB.values().size()+1);
    user.setUri("/user-management/"+user.getId());
    DB.put(user.getId(), user);
    return Response.status(201).contentLocation(new 
    URI(user.getUri())).build();
}

static
{
    Note user1 = new Note();
    user1.setId(1);
    user1.setFname("John");
    user1.setLname("Wick");
    user1.setUri("/user-management/1");

    Note user2 = new Note();
    user2.setId(2);
    user2.setFname("Harry");
    user2.setLname("Potter");
    user2.setUri("/user-management/2");

    DB.put(user1.getId(), user1);
    DB.put(user2.getId(), user2);
}

}
```

And i thing the import Code in my Angular is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import{Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable}   from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import{User}  from '../user';


@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UserService {
private baseUrl:string='http://localhost:8080/api';
private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
private options = new RequestOptions({headers:this.headers});
private user = new User();
constructor(private _http:Http) { }

getUsers(){
return this._http.get(this.baseUrl+'/users',this.options)
  .map((response:Response)=>response.json())
  .catch(this.errorHandler);
 }

  getUser(id:Number){
  return this._http.get(this.baseUrl+'/user/'+id,this.options)
  .map((response:Response)=>response.json())
  .catch(this.errorHandler);
 }

 deleteUser(id:Number){
 return 
 this._http.delete(this.baseUrl+'/user/'+id,this.options)
 .map((response:Response)=>response.json())
 .catch(this.errorHandler);
 }


createUser(user:User){
return this._http.post(this.baseUrl+'/user',JSON.stringify(user),  
this.options).map((response:Response)=>response.json())
  .catch(this.errorHandler);
}

updateUser(user:User){
return this._http.put(this.baseUrl+'/user',JSON.stringify(user),  
this.options).map((response:Response)=>response.json())
  .catch(this.errorHandler);
}

errorHandler(error:Response){
return Observable.throw(error||"SERVER ERROR");
}

setter(user:User){
 this.user=user;
}

getter(){
return this.user;
}

}
```

Looking with a DevTool the error Massage is:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'of 
type 'object'. 
NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
at NgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/
fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngOnChanges (common.js:3379)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:10093)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:11363)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:11325)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11962)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11922)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ListuserComponent.html:12)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11914)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11307)
at callViewAction (core.js:11548)
View_ListuserComponent_0 @ ListuserComponent.html:12
```

i thnig the problem is somewhere in this class:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import{UserService}  from '../../shared_service/user.service';
 import{User}  from '../../user';
 import{Router}  from '@angular/router';

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-listuser',
  templateUrl: './listuser.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listuser.component.css']
  })
  export class ListuserComponent implements OnInit {
  private users:User[];
  constructor(private _userService:UserService, 
  private _router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  this._userService.getUsers().subscribe(user=>{
    { this.users = user};
  },(error)=>{
    console.log(error);
  })
  }

deleteUser(user){
this._userService.deleteUser(user.id).subscribe((data)=>{
    this.users.splice(this.users.indexOf(user),1);
},(error)=>{
  console.log(error);
});
}

  updateUser(user){  
  this._userService.setter(user);
  this._router.navigate(['/op']);


  } 
  newUser(){
  let user = new User();
  this._userService.setter(user);
 this._router.navigate(['/op']);

 } 

 }
```

And i saw on localhost:8080/api/users/ that my backend works fine but in my frontend on localhost:4200 it doesn't show me my Data. Does someone know where the problem is and can help me please?

Comment: The error is saying there's a problem binding the `ngFor`. Are you using the `users` array for this? If so, this might be the cause. You are not initializing it, so until it's initialized (when the request finishes), the value is null, which may be a problem for the binding. Try initializing it with an empty array.

Comment: how i can do this :) can you give me an example ?

Comment: `private users:User[] = []`. Now sure if this will solve the problem or not. I can't tell from the information you've provided, what the exact error is.

Comment: Now I initializing it with an empty Array and i change all:
.map((response:Response)=>response.json()) 
to
.map((response:Response)=>response.json().users)

Now the error is gone, but it still doesn't work, my frontend doesn't show me the data from localhost:8080/api/users and i don't have an error massage anymore.

Comment: Look att the network tab in the dev tools. Look for any details that may provide some useful information about the request and response for debugging. Do some debugging on the server side. There's still not enough information for us to help you.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use:

```
@CrossOrigin
```

Annotation on your Controller class, like;

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
...
@CrossOrigin
public class NoteController {
...
```

Or on each entry points, like:

```
@CrossOrigin
...
public Response deleteUser(@PathParam("id") int id) throws 
...
```